# Possible fingerprinting for tiling window managers

Tags: linux, fingerprinting

Could tiling window managers fingerprint users and render letter-boxing useless?

Tiling WM change and resize windows suddenly and move them around in a grid. The resize behavior is different than the resize in Desktop Environments.

Is it discouraged to use tor in tiling WM?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *how* you're resizing the window. If it's a VM client that **does not** escalate the resize event and just resizes it's own viewport - then it's OK to use them. If it's a browser window directly - well, yes: it can be used for fingerprinting like you see it